# Having issues with an array of pointers in another array

Tags: c

this assignment of mine has a structure pointer with an array of item in it and im having trouble declaring it correctly to scan data into is. any help would be greatly appreciated Ive included both structures and the two functions that interact with them for reference and i have commented the line that appears to be the issue, if it is commented out it compiles and runs for the first function but if it is active it gets only the first number and returns -1067542 instead of 0

```
typedef struct item 
{
     int itemID;
     int numParts;
} item;

typedef struct recipe 
{
     int numItems;
     item* itemList;
     int totalParts;
} recipe;


recipe* readRecipe()
{
    int i, j;
    recipe *smoothieList;
    smoothieList = (recipe*)malloc(sizeof(recipe));
    fscanf(infile, "%d", &smoothieList->numItems);
    printf("%d", smoothieList->numItems);

    //I believe the following line is the source of my issue but im not sure
    //how to correctly do this
    **smoothieList->itemList = (item*)malloc(sizeof(item)* smoothieList->numItems);**
    for(i=0; i<smoothieList->numItems; i++)
    {
        //not sure how to work this, i think the number of iterations of pointer is confusing me
        fscanf(infile, "%d", smoothieList->itemList->itemID);
        fscanf(infile, "%d", smoothieList->itemList->numParts);
        smoothieList->totalParts += smoothieList->itemList->numParts;
    }

    return smoothieList;
}

recipe** readAllRecipes(int *numRecipes)
{
    recipe** smoothieList;
    int i, j, k;
    smoothieList = (recipe**)malloc(sizeof(recipe*) * (*numRecipes));
    for(i=0; i<*numRecipes; i++)
    {
        smoothieList[i] = readRecipe();
        printf("%d", smoothieList[i]->numItems);
    }
    return smoothieList;
}
```

Comment: `fscanf(infile, "%d", smoothieList->itemList->itemID);` That is wrong for multiple reasons. Firstly it's not indexing into the `itemList` array so always using the first element. Secondly `itemId` is an `int` but `fscanf` requires pointers. Should be `fscanf(infile, "%d", &smoothieList->itemList[i].itemID)`. Same for the line after that.

Comment: `smoothieList->totalParts += smoothieList->itemList->numParts;` That is wrong because it uses an uninitialized value. Set `totalParts` to `0` before the `for` loop.

Comment: Should also do basic error checking. In particular should check the return value of all `fscanf` and `malloc` calls and do flag an error if they fail.

Comment: so ```smoothieList->itemList = (item*)malloc(sizeof(item)* smoothieList->numItems);``` is not where i made my actual error? also would ```fscan``` then turn into ```&smoothieList->itemList[i].``` instead of ```[i]->```

Comment: The `malloc` looks ok. Yes `.` instead of `->`. I already show that in my comment.

Comment: oh sorry yea i see it now thank you so much, it seems like every step forward or problem/solution i figure out i immediately run into another.

Comment: `smoothieList->itemList = malloc (smoothieList->numItems * sizeof *smoothieList->itemList);` In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) If you use the dererferenced pointer to set *type-size*, you will never get the type-size wrong.

Comment: ```void freeRecipes(recipe** allRecipes, int numRecipes)
{
    int i, j;

    /*for(i=0; i<numRecipes; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<allRecipes->numItems; j++)
        {
            int k;
        }
    }``` my compiler is telling gme there is something wrong with the ```->``` in this

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comments, including why in C you don't need to cast the return of `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`), it looks like you know what the pieces to dynamic allocation are, you just don't know how to put them all together yet.

Dynamic allocation in C is a basic way to handle storage an unknown number of items. When you are allocating for nested struct, it is no more difficult (conceptually) that allocating storage for a single pointer. The housekeeping for what you need to allocate for and when just becomes a little more involved.

The key to anything, whether allocating storage or reading input, is the ***validate, validate, validate*** each step along the way. This becomes critical for handling nested allocations, because when, (not **if**), an allocation or input fails, you must clean up (`free()`) any allocated memory to that point before returning an error condition. If you fail to `free()` memory associated with any one partially-allocated struct where the read or allocation failed -- your code will **leak memory** (bad).

With that as a backdrop, you can envision what you need to do fairly easily. Whenever you are using a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `type` (e.g. a double-pointer), the allocation is a two-step process. (1) you must first allocate **pointers** (2) to which you will assign the address for an allocated and filled struct, e.g.

```
Allocated       Allocated
Pointers        Recipe Struct          Allocated
                                       ItemList
+----+     +---------------------+
| p1 | ->  | allocated recipe[0] | -> +----------+
+----+     +---------------------+    | itemList |  ->  item, item, item
| p2 | ->  | allocated recipe[1] | -> +----------+
+----+     +---------------------+    | itemList |  ->  item, item, item
| p3 |     |         ...         |    +----------+
+----+                                |   ...    |
| p4 |
+----+
| p5 |
 ....
```

Focusing on allocating for a single `struct recipe` and its allocated `itemList`, one way to minimize the cleanup you need on error, is to use a *temporary* `struct recipe` to fill thereby delaying allocation of the actual `struct recipe` you will return until you have filled and validated your temporary struct. That way for any intervening failure, all you need worry about freeing for cleanup is `itemList` if the failure occurs after it has been allocated.

Passing the open `FILE *` pointer as a parameter to your function, you could do:

```c
recipe *readRecipe (FILE *infile)
{
    recipe current = { .numItems = 0 };     /* temporary struct to fill */
    recipe *smoothieList = NULL;            /* pointer to allocate */
    
    /* VALIDATE every user-input */
    if (fscanf (infile, "%d", &current.numItems) != 1) {
        if (!feof(infile)) {        /* if not EOF, error */
            fputs ("error: read of numItems failed.\n", stderr);
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    
    /* allocate current.numItems * sizeof *current.itemList */
    current.itemList = malloc (current.numItems * sizeof *current.itemList);
    if (!current.itemList) {
        perror ("malloc-current.itemList");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    /* loop reading all items */
    for (int i = 0; i < current.numItems; i++) {
        if (fscanf (infile, "%d %d", 
            &current.itemList[i].itemID,
            &current.itemList[i].numParts) != 2) {
            fputs ("error: read of itemID and/or numParts failed.\n", stderr);
            free (current.itemList);
            return NULL;
        }
        current.totalParts += current.itemList[i].numParts;
    }
    
    /* allocate storage for current struct and VALIDATE */
    if (!(smoothieList = malloc (sizeof *smoothieList))) {
        perror ("malloc-smoothieList");
        free (current.itemList);
        return NULL;
    }
    
    *smoothieList = current;    /* assign current to allocated struct */
    
    return smoothieList;        /* return allocated struct */
}
```

Similarly, when reading all recipes from your file, you can employ a *temporary* pointer and ensure a recipe is returned, filled and allocated, before you allocate an additional pointer for your list.

(**Note:**, when you use `realloc()` to add more pointers to your list, you always `realloc()` to a **temporary pointer**. Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails returning `NULL`, you overwrite the address to your collection of pointers creating a memory leak.)

For example you could do:

```c
recipe **readAllRecipes (FILE *infile, int *numRecipes)
{
    recipe *current = NULL;         /* temporary ptr for current recipie */
    recipe **smoothieList = NULL;   /* pointer to pointer for list */
    int nrecipes = 0;               /* counter, num recipies read */
    
    /* loop reading each recipe in file */
    while ((current = readRecipe (infile))) {
        /* realloc using temp pointer to avoid leak on NULL return */
        void *tmp = realloc (smoothieList, (nrecipes + 1) * sizeof *smoothieList);
        if (!tmp) { /* VALIDATE every reallocation */
            perror ("malloc-smoothieList pointer");
            break;
        }
        smoothieList = tmp;                 /* assign realloc'ed block */
        smoothieList[nrecipes] = current;   /* assign current to alloc'ed ptr */
        nrecipes += 1;                      /* increment counter */
    }
    
    *numRecipes = nrecipes;         /* update value at mem address */
    
    return smoothieList;            /* return alloc'ed pointers and recipes */
}
```

Now putting it altogether in a short example program you could do:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct item {
     int itemID;
     int numParts;
} item;

typedef struct recipe {
     int numItems;
     item* itemList;
     int totalParts;
} recipe;

recipe *readRecipe (FILE *infile)
{
    recipe current = { .numItems = 0 };     /* temporary struct to fill */
    recipe *smoothieList = NULL;            /* pointer to allocate */
    
    /* VALIDATE every user-input */
    if (fscanf (infile, "%d", &current.numItems) != 1) {
        if (!feof(infile)) {        /* if not EOF, error */
            fputs ("error: read of numItems failed.\n", stderr);
        }
        return NULL;
    }
    
    /* allocate current.numItems * sizeof *current.itemList */
    current.itemList = malloc (current.numItems * sizeof *current.itemList);
    if (!current.itemList) {
        perror ("malloc-current.itemList");
        return NULL;
    }
    
    /* loop reading all items */
    for (int i = 0; i < current.numItems; i++) {
        if (fscanf (infile, "%d %d", 
            &current.itemList[i].itemID,
            &current.itemList[i].numParts) != 2) {
            fputs ("error: read of itemID and/or numParts failed.\n", stderr);
            free (current.itemList);
            return NULL;
        }
        current.totalParts += current.itemList[i].numParts;
    }
    
    /* allocate storage for current struct and VALIDATE */
    if (!(smoothieList = malloc (sizeof *smoothieList))) {
        perror ("malloc-smoothieList");
        free (current.itemList);
        return NULL;
    }
    
    *smoothieList = current;    /* assign current to allocated struct */
    
    return smoothieList;        /* return allocated struct */
}

recipe **readAllRecipes (FILE *infile, int *numRecipes)
{
    recipe *current = NULL;         /* temporary ptr for current recipie */
    recipe **smoothieList = NULL;   /* pointer to pointer for list */
    int nrecipes = 0;               /* counter, num recipies read */
    
    /* loop reading each recipe in file */
    while ((current = readRecipe (infile))) {
        /* realloc using temp pointer to avoid leak on NULL return */
        void *tmp = realloc (smoothieList, (nrecipes + 1) * sizeof *smoothieList);
        if (!tmp) { /* VALIDATE every reallocation */
            perror ("malloc-smoothieList pointer");
            break;
        }
        smoothieList = tmp;                 /* assign realloc'ed block */
        smoothieList[nrecipes] = current;   /* assign current to alloc'ed ptr */
        nrecipes += 1;                      /* increment counter */
    }
    
    *numRecipes = nrecipes;         /* update value at mem address */
    
    return smoothieList;            /* return alloc'ed pointers and recipes */
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    int nrecipes = 0;               /* number of recipes read */
    recipe **list = NULL;           /* pointer to pointer for list */
    
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    
    list = readAllRecipes (fp, &nrecipes);  /* read all recipes, build list */
    
    if (fp != stdin)    /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
    
    if (!list) {        /* valdate list not NULL */
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nrecipes; i++) {                /* loop recipes */
        printf ("recipe %d:\n", i);                     /* output number */
        for (int j = 0; j < list[i]->numItems; j++) {   /* loop items */
            printf ("  %4d  %4d\n",                     /* output items */
                    list[i]->itemList[j].itemID,
                    list[i]->itemList[j].numParts);
        }
        /* output total */
        printf ("  ----------\n        %4d\n\n", list[i]->totalParts);
        
        free (list[i]->itemList);   /* free itemList when done */
        free (list[i]);             /* free recipe */
    }
    
    free (list);        /* don't forget to free pointers */
}
```

(**note:** the program expects you will pass the filename to read as the 1st argument, or you will provide data on `stdin`)

**Example Input File**

Providing 3 smoothies worth of data, the first with one `itemID`, the 2nd with 2 and so on.. you could use:

```
$ cat dat/smoothies.txt
1 1001 2
2 1001 2 1002 1
3 1001 4 1002 2 1003 4
```

(**note:** the format of your file is somewhat flexible given how `fscanf()` using the `"%d"` format specifier will ignore leading whitespace -- including `'\n'` characters which are whitespace)

**Example Use/Output**

Running the program it stores all recipes, item lists and items and then outputs each along with the total parts. The itemIDs are `1001`, `1002`, etc.. e.g.

```
$ ./bin/smoothie_recipes dat/smoothies.txt
recipe 0:
  1001     2
  ----------
           2

recipe 1:
  1001     2
  1002     1
  ----------
           3

recipe 2:
  1001     4
  1002     2
  1003     4
  ----------
          10
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/smoothie_recipes dat/smoothies.txt
==24567== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==24567== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==24567== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==24567== Command: ./bin/smoothie_recipes dat/smoothies.txt
==24567==
recipe 0:
  1001     2
  ----------
           2

recipe 1:
  1001     2
  1002     1
  ----------
           3

recipe 2:
  1001     4
  1002     2
  1003     4
  ----------
          10

==24567==
==24567== HEAP SUMMARY:
==24567==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==24567==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 12 frees, 5,840 bytes allocated
==24567==
==24567== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==24567==
==24567== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==24567== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

There is a lot here, so take your time and make sure you understand the nesting of the structures and allocations as well as how you free the memory associated with your collection when you are done. Let me know if you have further questions.